# yii2 save, check if exist, if yes give id back, if not, create (and give id back)

Tags: save, yii2, exists

I wonder if there is a function in yii2 I imagine similar as save(), what would do the following: check if the given record exist in the db with these attributes, if yes, it would give back id, if not, it would create it and give back id. I think it would be cool. Probably there is something like that. Can you please help me where can I find it? Thank you!

Comment: depends on your unique column. Post your database fields and which fields are unique besides primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's that specific functionality but in addition to save, you can also use [exists](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#exists%28%29-detail).

```
$exists = ModelName::find()->where( [ 'id' => 1 ] )->exists();

if($exists) {
  //it exists

} else {
  //doesn't exist so create record

}
```

Comment: Thanks! nice and clean!

Answer (score 3):

```
$model = ModelName::findOne(1) ?? new ModelName();
//or 
$model = ModelName::find()->where(['id' => 1])->one() ?? new ModelName();
```

1. if 'id' is primapy key
2. if not

Answer (score 1):

method [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail) from BaseActiveRecord class have similar functionality 
but it returns a boolean whether the saving succeeds. 
You can get primary key value after save() calling

[$model->getPrimaryKey();](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#getPrimaryKey()-detail)